# Snell's law using Zoeppritz equation by matrices

Tags: python, mathematics, numpy, physics

I have created the following code to calculate Snell's law angles, based on Zoeppritz equations on complex plane. The code works, seems it is returning valid values, but after all the code just looks a complete mess. Maybe there are nicer way to deal with complex values and matrices using numpy. Any hints to make this more pythonic and readable? For example down before return I use a for loop to calculate each coefficient, I use a temporary array to swap values is there another way (faster/nicer) to do that on numpy? Or the method I use to handle imaginary on critical angles.

```
def calculate_matrix(phi0,alpha1,beta1,rho1,alpha2,beta2,rho2):
    """Calculate angles using Snell's law
    \frac{\sin(\phi_1)}{\sin(\phi_2)}=\frac{\alpha_1}{\alpha_2}    
    Parameters:
        phi0:   Wave incident angle media 1 on point over the interface
        alpha1: P-wave speed on media 0
        beta1:  S-wave speed on media 0
        rho1:   Media 1 Density
        alpha2: P-wave speed on media 1
        beta2:  S-wave speed on media 1
        rho2:   Media 2 Density
    """

    """Used variables:    
    pp:  Ray Parameter
    phi1: angle of reflected P-wave
    phi2: angle of transmitted P-wave
    psi1: angle of reflected S-wave
    psi2: angle of transmitted S-wave
    """

    # Ray Parameter
    pp=np.math.sin(phi0)/alpha1

    # phi1 is always equal incident angle
    phi1=phi0

    # Will never be greater than incident angle since V_s < V_p
    psi1=np.math.asin(pp*beta1)    

    # For angles that are in the second layer they might be critical
    alpha2pp=pp*alpha2    
    alpha2pp2=alpha2pp**2

    beta2pp=pp*beta2
    beta2pp2=beta2pp**2

    cc=1-2*beta2pp2

    # Calculate all imaginary coefficients
    if alpha2pp > 1:
        phi2=np.math.pi/2
        j20=(-((alpha2pp2-1)**(0.5)))*1j
        j23=(-rho2/rho1 * beta2**2 * alpha1/beta1**2*2*pp*(alpha2pp2-1)**(0.5))*1j
    elif alpha2pp < -1:
        phi2=-np.math.pi/2
        j20=((alpha2pp2-1)**(0.5))*1j
        j23=(rho2/rho1 * beta2**2 * alpha1/beta1**2*2*pp*(alpha2pp2-1)**(0.5))*1j        
    else:
        j20=0
        j23=0    
        phi2=np.math.asin(alpha2pp)

    if beta2pp > 1:
        psi2=np.math.pi/2
        j31=(beta2pp2-1)**(0.5)*1j
        j32=(-rho2/rho1*beta2*beta2/alpha1*2*pp*(beta2pp2-1)**(0.5))*1j
    elif beta2pp < -1:
        psi2=-np.math.pi/2
        j31=-((beta2pp2-1)**(0.5))*1j
        j32=(rho2/rho1*beta2*beta2/alpha1*2*pp*(beta2pp2-1)**(0.5))*1j
    else:
        j31=0
        j32=0
        psi2=np.math.asin(beta2pp)

    # Main matrix for an incident P wave    
    m = np.zeros((4,4),dtype="complex")
    v = np.zeros(4,dtype="complex")    

    m[0]=[  np.math.cos(phi1),
            -np.math.sin(phi1),
            -np.math.cos(2*psi1),
             np.math.sin(2*phi1)
             ]
    m[1]=[ -np.math.sin(psi1),
            -np.math.cos(psi1),
             np.math.sin(2*psi1)*(beta1/alpha1),
             np.math.cos(2*psi1)*(alpha1/beta1)
            ]

    if alpha2pp2 < 1:
        m[2]=[ 
            np.math.cos(phi2) + j20,
            alpha2pp,
            rho2/rho1 * alpha2/alpha1 * cc + j23,
            rho2/rho1 * beta2**2/beta1**2 * alpha1/alpha2 * np.math.sin(2*phi2)            
            ]
    else:
        m[2]=[ 
            0 + j20,        
            alpha2pp,
            rho2/rho1 * alpha2/alpha1 * cc + j23,
            0 
            ]

    if beta2pp2 < 1:
        m[3] = [
            beta2pp,
            -np.math.cos(psi2)+j31,
            rho2/rho1*beta2/alpha1*np.math.sin(2*psi2)+j32,
            -rho2/rho1*alpha1*beta2/beta1/beta1*cc
        ]
    else:
        m[3]= [
            beta2pp,
            0+j31,
            0+j32,
            -rho2/rho1*alpha1*beta2/beta1/beta1*cc            
        ]   

    v=[
        np.math.cos(phi1),
        np.math.sin(phi1),
        np.math.cos(2*psi1),
        np.math.sin(2*phi1),
    ]

    detm=np.linalg.det(m)    
    detm_norm=np.linalg.norm(detm)
    #print(detm)
    #print(detm_norm)

    vd=np.zeros(4,dtype="complex")
    vn=np.zeros(4,dtype="float")
    phase=np.zeros(4,dtype="float")
    for i in range(4):
        # Make a copy of i-th column vector from matrix m
        cvt=m[i]

        # Copy vector to matrix i-th column of matrix m
        m[i]=v

        # Calculate the determinant and store on a array
        vd[i]=np.linalg.det(m)
        vn[i]=np.linalg.norm(vd[i])/detm_norm
        phase[i]=np.math.atan2(vd[i].real*detm.real-vd[i].imag*detm.imag,
                               vd[i].real*detm.real+vd[i].imag*detm.imag )

        # Copy the vector back    
        m[i]=cvt

    # a1,b1,a2,b3
    return vd, vn, phase
```